# Update query mysql with JDBC

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, jdbc

![enter image description here][1]I am trying to update data in table of MySQL database.
I am unable to do, since I am beginner so I have no idea how to do , kindly guide me properly.
I would be thankful to you..............

Part of cade that generates exception:

```
        java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = conection.prepareStatement("UPDATE  patient_details set  `Reg_Date`='?', `Name`='?', `Father_Husband_Name`='?', `Address`='?', `City`='?', `Cell_No`='?', `Martial_Status`='?', `Gender`='?', `Status`='?', `Age`='?' where 'Reg_No'='temp'"); 
                    statement.setInt(1, temp); 
                      statement.setString(2,textField_3.getText());
                      statement.setString(3,textField_1.getText());
                      statement.setString(4,textField_2.getText());
                      statement.setString(5,textArea.getText());
                      statement.setString(6,textField_4.getText());
                      statement.setString(7,textField_5.getText());
                      statement.setString(8,(String) comboBox.getSelectedItem()); 
                      statement.setString(9,(String) comboBox_1.getSelectedItem()); 
                      statement.setString(10,(String) comboBox_2.getSelectedItem()); 

                      statement.setInt(11,temp1); 

                      statement.executeUpdate();
```

Exception is:
parameter out of range(1>number of paarameters which is 0)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html this will help you

Comment: it would help if you would provide the entire exception stack trace

Comment: o.k just see wait please...

Answer (score 0):

YOu set 11 parameters but only have 10 ? in the statement.  The last part of the statement, the where clause - you have

```
where 'Reg_No'='temp'"
```

which is not a variable.  You should be able to drop the statement

```
  statement.setInt(11,temp1);
```